# What shape comes next?

Tags: logical-deduction, pattern

What shape comes next?

triangle pentagon square
square hexagon hexagon square
pentagon hexagon hexagon hexagon square triangle
hexagon octagon octagon octagon octagon ????

> Looking at the hint already? Shame on you! Anyway, here it is: Often Same

Comment: Are you sure those hexagons in the third row shouldn't be heptagons? And should that triangle be there?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

answer:

> square

explanation:

**Numbers** are the sum of the angles in each shape

multiply the first digit by itself, then calculate the sum of the remaining digits. The sum now should be equal to the product.

```
3 5 4          : 3*3 = 9   [ 5 + 4 ]               = 9

4 6 6 4        : 4*4 = 16  [ 6 + 6 + 4 ]           = 16

5 6 6 6 4 3    : 5*5 = 25  [ 6 + 6 + 6 + 4 + 3 ]   = 25

6 8 8 8 8      : 6*6 = 36  [ 8 + 8 + 8 + 8 + (4) ] = 36
```

> hexagon octagon octagon octagon octagon [square]